# 2x DeclareNewSectionCommand leading to "capacity exceeded"

Tags: luatex, koma-script

I'm trying to create two new section commands in a `scrartcl` document, the second basing on the first.

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\DeclareNewSectionCommand[
    afterskip=1.5ex plus .2ex,
    beforeskip=-3.25ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex,
    indent=0pt,
    level=2,
    font=\usekomafont{subsection},
    tocindent=1.5em,
    tocnumwidth=2.3em,
    counterwithin=section,
    style=section]{subphase}

\DeclareNewSectionCommand[
    afterskip=1.5ex plus .2ex,
    beforeskip=-3.25ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex,
    indent=0pt,
    level=3,
    font=\usekomafont{subsection},
    tocindent=2.0em,
    tocnumwidth=2.3em,
    counterwithin=subphase,
    style=section]{task}

\begin{document}
 \section{A}
 \subphase{Phase}
 \task{Task}
 \task{Task}
 \task{Task}
 \subphase{Phase}
 \task{Task}
 \task{Task}
 \task{Task}
\end{document}
```

Using `lualatex` it spits out the following error message:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\thesubphase ...sname the\scr@local@counterwithin 
                                                  \endcsname .\arabic {subph...
l.26  \subphase{Phase}
```

So, where's the problem?

I'm new to KOMA-Script, so this might be a total rookie mistake.

## Update 1:

might have been an outdated TeXlive installation. Installing a 2017 version right now to see if it helps.

## Update 2:

Installing a newer TeXlive version solved the issue. Seems like it was indeed an outdated KOMA-script version.

Comment: Works here, with pdfLaTeX as well with LuaLaTeX. Please post the first error message in the log file. By the way: I'm curious, what is the idea of defining two section commands?

Comment: The idea is to have a different type of sub-structure in a document for one specific section without redefining the subsection and subsubsection commands.

Comment: Maybe you are using KOMA-Script Version 3.19a or earlier. There was a bug (see https://komascript.de/release3.19a, German) that was fixed in version 3.20. Current version is 3.24.

Comment: @esdd This might be the reason. My TeXlive environment seems rather outdated (it's the one installed through APT in Ubuntu 16.04), a 2015 version. I'm downloading 2017 at the moment and will see if that solves the problem.

Comment: @esdd You were right. Updating TeXlive solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to outdated software, solved by updating.

Comment: I agree. It can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually installing a newer TeXlive version (20170524) solved the issue (original one was 2015 from the Ubuntu 16.04 APT repository). Seems like it was indeed an outdated KOMA-script version.